# PHP displaying image in html not working

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to get this code working but yeah it displays nothing. It would be much appreciated if you could point out what the problem is

returning banner() right after the function works but if i bring it inside the html it doesnt display anything and also for some reason the isup_tf() function doesnt work either if i display the text directly.

```
<?php
    function isup_tf(){
        $try = @fsockopen("217.182.63.64", "9339", $errno, $errstr, 0.5);
        if($try){
            return true;
            }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function banner(){
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

        $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('banner.jpg');

        $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

        $font_path = 'afb.ttf';

        $name = "DarkSoul Server 1 | Unlimited MODS";
        $status = (isup_tf() ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE");

        imagettftext($jpg_image, 21, 0, 12, 48, $white, $font_path, $name);
        imagettftext($jpg_image, 40, 0, 12, 121, $white, $font_path, $status);

        imagejpeg($jpg_image);

        imagedestroy($jpg_image);
    }
?>

<html>
    <style>
        * { text-align: center !important; color: white; font-size: 1em;}
        p { color: white; }
    </style>
    <body style="background: #282828;">
        <div>
            <h1>Banner</h1>
            <?php banner(); ?>
            <h1>Status</h1>
            <?php return (isup_tf() ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE"); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: set PHP show error then sees what kind of errors.

Comment: banner creates an actual jpeg image, not a <img> tag, so you would want to separate that code into a different file that you can call from an image tag, like `<img src='mybannercode.php'>`  You should echo rather than return the result of your ternary function wrapping isup_tf.

Answer (score 0):

**For isup_tf()** try this:

```
<?php echo (isup_tf() ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE"); ?>
```

---

**For `banner()`**, try this:

```
<img src="<?php return banner(); ?>" alt="Banner">
```

or this:

```
<img src="<?php echo banner(); ?>" alt="Banner">
```

or this:

```
<img src="<?php banner(); ?>" alt="Banner">
```

**[RECOMMENDED]** If upper options are not working, than bring `banner()` content (not with function definition and end!) into a `banner.php` file and then use like this:

```
<img src="banner.php" alt="Banner">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code:

```
<?php

    if ( isset($_GET['image']) )
    {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        banner();   
    }

    function status(){
        $try = @fsockopen("217.182.63.64", "9339", $errno, $errstr, 0.5);
        if($try){
            return true;
            }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function banner(){
        $jpg_image   = imagecreatefromjpeg('banner.jpg');   
        $white       = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
        $font_path   = 'afb.ttf';
        $name        = "DarkSoul Server 1 | Unlimited MODS";
        $status      = (status() ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE");

        imagettftext($jpg_image, 21, 0, 12, 48, $white, $font_path, $name);
        imagettftext($jpg_image, 40, 0, 12, 121, $white, $font_path, $status);

        imagejpeg($jpg_image);

        imagedestroy($jpg_image);
    }
?>

<html>
    <style>
        * { text-align: center !important; color: white; font-size: 1em;}
        p { color: white; }
    </style>
    <body style="background: #282828;">
        <div>
            <h1>Banner</h1>
            <img src="?image">
            <h1>Status</h1>
            <?php echo (status() ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE"); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```